# how to build spring ldap project using maven?

Tags: spring, maven, ldap

I checked out the spring-ldap project [from github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap). The project is setup with gradle, but I would like to build it with maven. But the github project was not setup with maven. So how to apply this project with maven?

Comment: You don't as it is intended to be build with gradle. If you want maven you would have to create your own pom (translated from the gradle file). But why build it yourself?

Comment: how to translate gradle file  to pom.xml ?

Comment: Open file, see what it does, create pom, trial and error. But why? There is a gradle wrapper (the gradlew files) which automatically download everything for building. Why make it difficult and try to get your own build running.\

Comment: i am new in spring and ldap both . i had created spring mvc project using maven . i dont know anything about gradle . so how can i implement  ldap to a spring mvc maven project

Comment: By adding a dependency you don't need the project for that.

Comment: please tell this from initial level . clearly said that i am new . can you provide any link by which i can do this ??

Comment: If you don't know how to add a dependency to maven I strongly suggest a read of the maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)... The dependency to add is described [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ldap/) which is pretty much copy-paste...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i know that how to add a dependency . which dependencies are added by which the ldap implemented to the spring mvc .

Comment: You don't implement LDAP you just use the Spring LDAP library. You don't build anything you just use the provided classes like any other library you add. Also this has nothing to do With Spring or Spring MVC ... And please don't ask the same question twice !